# Problema com imagebuttom em listview

Tags: android, listview

Olá, tenho um problema que ao mostrar o ultimo item do listview na tela, o imagebuttom do ultimo item e os outros da tela param de funcionar, ao rolar a tela novamente e esconder este ultimo item, todos os imagembuttons da tela voltam a funcionar. Isso acontece também com click longo, que deveria abrir o contextMenu.

> Esse problema não apresenta erro, somente não mostra o contextMenu.

Activity

```
public class ClientsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /*-------------------------------------------+
    | VARIAVEIS DE CONTROLE DA LISTAGEM DA QUERY |
    +--------------------------------------------+*/
    private int increment = 0;    // NUMERO QUE SE ENCONTRA O SEQUENCIAL
    private int limit = 20;   // QUANTIDADE DE LISTAGEM POR VEZ NA QUERY

    /*-------------------+
    | LIST VIEW E FOOTER |
    +--------------------+*/
    private ListView lvClient;
    private ClientListAdapter adapter;
    private TextView emptyText;

    /*---------------------------------------+
    | TELA COM OBJETO VISUAL DE CARREGAMENTO |
    +----------------------------------------+*/
    private View loadView;
    private boolean isLoading = false;
    private Handler mHandler;

    /*---------------------------------------+
  | ALERT DIALOG COM AS OPCOES DE FILTRO   |
  +----------------------------------------+*/
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogFilter;
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogShow;
    private int filtroSelecionado = 0;
    private int showSelecionado = 0;

    /*---------------------------------------+
    | ALERT DIALOG COM AS OPCOES DE ORDENACAO   |
    +----------------------------------------+*/
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogOrderBy;
    private int orderBySelecionado;

    private HashMap<Integer, String> orderOptions = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private HashMap<Integer, String> orderOrientationOptions = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private String orderField = "A1_NOME";
    private String orderOrientation = "ASC";

    private String selectionFilter = "";
    private String viewFilter = "";
    private String[] selectionFilterArgs = null;

    NavigationView navigation;

    MenuClass menu = MenuClass.getInstance();

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */

    private Cursor cursor;


    /*------------------+
    | CLASSE DE CRIACCO |
    +-------------------+*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clients);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            filtroSelecionado = savedInstanceState.getInt("filtroSelecionado");
            showSelecionado = savedInstanceState.getInt("showSelecionado");
            orderOrientation = savedInstanceState.getString("orderOrientation", orderOrientation);
        }

        //Controla tela ligada
        if(Prefs.getBoolean(getApplicationContext(), Prefs.CHAVE_SCREEN)){
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }

        //Controla de rotação de tela
        if (!Prefs.getBoolean(getApplicationContext(), Prefs.ROTATE_SCREEN)) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
        }

        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_clients);

        orderOptions.put(0, "CNPJ/CPF");
        orderOptions.put(1, "Razão social");
        orderOptions.put(2, "Nome fantasia");
        orderOptions.put(3, "CEP");
        orderOptions.put(4, "Cidade+Estado");

        orderOrientationOptions.put(0, "Crescente");
        orderOrientationOptions.put(1, "Decrescente");

        /*------------------------------------------------------------------+
        | CRIA OBJETO QUE IRA APRESENTAR O LOAD QUANDO FOR CARREGAR INFORMACCES |
        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+*/
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        loadView = li.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);

        String orderBy = orderField + " " + orderOrientation;

        /*----------+
        | LIST VIEW |
        +-----------+*/
        mHandler    = new MyHandler();
        lvClient   = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_client);
        emptyText   = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emptyText);
        adapter     = new ClientListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getMoreData(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs, orderBy, true)){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setBackgroundColor(((position % 2 == 1) ? ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorZebraListView, null) : Color.WHITE));
                view.setLongClickable(true);
                return view;
            }

        };

        lvClient.addFooterView(loadView);
        lvClient.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvClient.removeFooterView(loadView);
        lvClient.setEmptyView(emptyText);

        registerForContextMenu(lvClient);

        /*-------------------------------+
        | QUANDO CLICAR NO ITEM DA LISTA |
        +--------------------------------+*/
        lvClient.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                /*--------------------------------------------------------------------+
                | PASSA POR PARAMETRO O ID DO PRODUTO PARA PODER VISUALIZAR O DETALHE |
                +---------------------------------------------------------------------+*/
                startActivity(new Intent(ClientsActivity.this, ClientsDetailActivity.class).putExtra("nAt", (int) view.getTag()));

            }
        });

        /*-------------------+
        | CONTROLE DE SCROLL |
        +--------------------+*/
        lvClient.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                int btn_initPosY = fab.getScrollY();
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    fab.animate().cancel();
                    fab.animate().translationYBy(350);
                } else {
                    fab.animate().cancel();
                    fab.animate().translationY(btn_initPosY);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                view.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

                if(view.getLastVisiblePosition() == totalItemCount-1 && lvClient.getCount() >= limit && isLoading == false) {
                    isLoading       = true;
                    Thread thread   = new ThreadGetMoreData();
                    thread.start();
                }
            }

        });

        //Monta o Filtro
        alertDialogFilter = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        buildFilterDialog();

        alertDialogShow = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        buildShowDialog();

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Snackbar.make(view, "Snackbar message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(ClientsActivity.this, NewSalesActivity.class));
            }
        });

        navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                menu.choiceMenu(getApplicationContext(), id);
                finish();
                return false;
            }
        });
        navigation.setItemIconTintList(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        int id = getIdCli(info);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(getNameCli(info)) ;
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, id , Menu.NONE, R.string.TITLE_MENU_FINANCEIRO_CLIENTE );
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, id , Menu.NONE, R.string.TITLE_MENU_VISUALIZAR_ITEM    );
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, id , Menu.NONE, R.string.TITLE_MENU_DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE  );
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, id , Menu.NONE, R.string.TITLE_MENU_COMPRAS_CLIENTE  );
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, id , Menu.NONE, R.string.TITLE_MENU_PEDIDOS_CLIENTE  );

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle() == getResources().getString(R.string.TITLE_MENU_FINANCEIRO_CLIENTE)) {
            cursor = new DBController(getBaseContext()).selectListData("SE1 JOIN SA1 AS SA1 ON (A1_COD = E1_CLIENTE AND A1_LOJA = E1_LOJA) ", null, "SA1.id = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(item.getItemId())}, null);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Nenhum título para este cliente!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(ClientsActivity.this, FinancialDetailActivity.class).putExtra("nAt", item.getItemId()));
            }
        } else { return false; }

        return true;
    }

    public String getNameCli(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info) {
        return ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).getText().toString();
    }

    public int getIdCli(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info) {
        return Integer.parseInt(((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cod)).getText().toString());
    }

    public void doEatIn(MenuItem mi) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your table will be ready soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void doTakeOut(MenuItem mi) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please pick up at the take-out window", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return (true);
    }

    public class MyHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:
                    // HABILITA NO RADAPE O CARREGANDO
                    lvClient.addFooterView(loadView);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    adapter.addListItemToAdapter((ArrayList<Client>) msg.obj); //Update data adapter and UI
                    lvClient.removeFooterView(loadView); //Remove loading view after update listview
                    isLoading = false;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    /*------------------------------------+
    | CRIA O ARRAY PARA MONTAR O LISTVIEW |
    +-------------------------------------+*/
    private ArrayList<Client> getMoreData(String selection,String[] selectionArgs, String orderBy, boolean isLimite) {
        if (!viewFilter.trim().equals("") && !selection.trim().equals("")) {
            selection = " AND " + selection;
        }

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String formDate = sdf.format(c.getTime()).toString();

        ArrayList<Client> lst  = new ArrayList<>();
        DBController dbCtrl     = new DBController(getBaseContext());
        String[] fieldTable = {"SA1.id", "A1_CGC", "A1_NOME", "A1_NREDUZ", "A1_END", "A1_MUN", "A1_EST", "A1_CEP", "A1_LC", "ifnull((SELECT SUM(E1_SALDO) FROM SE1 WHERE A1_COD = E1_CLIENTE AND A1_LOJA = E1_LOJA AND E1_VENCTO >= '"+formDate+"'),0) SALDO_A_DEV ", "ifnull((SELECT SUM(E1_SALDO) FROM SE1 WHERE A1_COD = E1_CLIENTE AND A1_LOJA = E1_LOJA AND E1_VENCTO < '"+formDate+"'),0) SALDO_DEV "};
        Cursor cursor = dbCtrl.selectListDataOrder("SA1", fieldTable, viewFilter+selection, selectionArgs, orderBy, (isLimite ? String.valueOf(increment) + "," + String.valueOf(limit) : null));
        increment += limit;

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(",##0.00");
            String creditLimit = formatter.format(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("A1_LC")));

            lst.add(new Client(
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A1_CGC")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A1_NREDUZ")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A1_NOME")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A1_END")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A1_MUN")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A1_EST")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A1_CEP")),
                    "R$ "+creditLimit,
                    cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("SALDO_A_DEV")),
                    cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("SALDO_DEV"))
            ));
        }
        return lst;
    }

    public class ThreadGetMoreData extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String orderBy = orderField + " " + orderOrientation;

            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);                                   //Add footer view after get data
            ArrayList<Client> lstResult = getMoreData(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs, orderBy, true);    //Search more data
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(1, lstResult);             //Send the result to Handle
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    public void updateListItens(String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        // RESET LIMIT
        increment = 0;
        limit = 20;

        String orderBy = orderField + " " + orderOrientation;

        lvClient.addFooterView(loadView);
        lvClient.setAdapter(null);
        lvClient.removeFooterView(loadView);
        lvClient.setEmptyView(emptyText);

        adapter = new ClientListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getMoreData(selection, selectionArgs, orderBy, true)) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setBackgroundColor(((position % 2 == 1) ? ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorZebraListView, null) : Color.WHITE));
                return view;
            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // TENTA ORDERNAR
        lvClient.addFooterView(loadView);
        lvClient.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvClient.removeFooterView(loadView);
        lvClient.setEmptyView(emptyText);
    }


    private void buildFilterDialog() {
        final String[] labels = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rg_filter_client);

        alertDialogFilter.setTitle("Filtrar por");
        alertDialogFilter.setSingleChoiceItems(labels, filtroSelecionado, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int posicao) {
                alertDialogFilter.setSingleChoiceItems(labels, posicao, this);
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                filtroSelecionado = posicao;
                if (filtroSelecionado == 0) {
                    updateListItens(null, null);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void buildShowDialog() {
        final String[] labels = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rg_show_clients);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        final String formDate = sdf.format(c.getTime()).toString();

        alertDialogShow.setTitle("Mostrar");
        alertDialogShow.setSingleChoiceItems(labels, showSelecionado, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int posicao) {
                alertDialogShow.setSingleChoiceItems(labels, posicao, this);
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                showSelecionado = posicao;
                if (showSelecionado == 0) {
                    viewFilter = "";
                    updateListItens(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs);
                }
                if (showSelecionado == 1) {
                    viewFilter = "A1_ISINVOICE > 0";
                    updateListItens(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs);
                }
                if (showSelecionado == 2) {
                    viewFilter = "A1_ISINVOICE <= 0";
                    updateListItens(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs);
                }
                if (showSelecionado == 3) {
                    viewFilter = " SALDO_A_DEV >= 0 AND SALDO_DEV <= 0 ";
                    updateListItens(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs);
                }
                if (showSelecionado == 4) {
                    viewFilter = " SALDO_DEV > 0 ";
                    updateListItens(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs);
                }
                if (showSelecionado == 5) {
                    viewFilter = " ((A1_ZCKALV1 != '' AND A1_ZDTALV1 != '' AND A1_ZDTALV1 < '"+formDate+"') OR (A1_ZCKALV2 != '' AND A1_ZDTALV2 != '' AND A1_ZDTALV2 < '"+formDate+"') OR (A1_ZCKALV3 != '' AND A1_ZDTALV3 != '' AND A1_ZDTALV3 < '"+formDate+"')) ";
                    updateListItens(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs);
                }
                if (showSelecionado == 6) {
                    viewFilter = " (((A1_ZNMALV1 = '' AND A1_ZDTALV1 = '') OR A1_ZDTALV1 >= '"+formDate+"') AND ((A1_ZNMALV2 = '' AND A1_ZDTALV2 = '') OR A1_ZDTALV2 >= '"+formDate+"') AND ((A1_ZNMALV3 = '' AND A1_ZDTALV3 = '') OR A1_ZDTALV3 >= '"+formDate+"')) ";
                    updateListItens(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void OrderScreen() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ClientsActivity.this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_order);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.setTitle("Ordenação");

        final Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
        final Button btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        final RadioGroup rgV = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiogroupVertical);
        final RadioGroup rgH = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiogroupHorizontal);
        final TextView tvText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tvText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        final LinearLayout li = new LinearLayout(ClientsActivity.this);
        li.setLayoutParams(params);
        li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : orderOptions.entrySet()) {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(ClientsActivity.this);
            radioButton.setText(entry.getValue());
            radioButton.setId(entry.getKey());
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams paramsRadio = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rgV.addView(radioButton, paramsRadio);
        }

        ((ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiogroupVertical)).addView(li);

        if (orderField.equals("A1_CGC")) {
            rgV.check(0);
        } else if (orderField.equals("A1_NOME")) {
            rgV.check(Integer.parseInt("1"));
        } else if (orderField.equals("A1_NREDUZ")) {
            rgV.check(Integer.parseInt("2"));
        } else if (orderField.equals("A1_CEP")) {
            rgV.check(Integer.parseInt("3"));
        } else if (orderField.equals("A1_MUN, A1_EST")) {
            rgV.check(Integer.parseInt("4"));
        }

        final LinearLayout li2 = new LinearLayout(ClientsActivity.this);
        li2.setLayoutParams(params);
        li2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : orderOrientationOptions.entrySet()) {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(ClientsActivity.this);
            radioButton.setText(entry.getValue());
            radioButton.setId(entry.getKey());
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams paramsRadio = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rgH.addView(radioButton, paramsRadio);
        }

        ((ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiogroupHorizontal)).addView(li2);

        if (orderOrientation.equals("DESC")) {
            rgH.check(Integer.parseInt("1"));
        } else {
            rgH.check(0);
        }

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int radioOption = rgV.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int radioOrientation = rgH.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                if (radioOption == 0) {
                    orderField = "A1_CGC";
                } else if (radioOption == 1) {
                    orderField = "A1_NOME";
                } else if (radioOption == 2) {
                    orderField = "A1_NREDUZ";
                } else if (radioOption == 3) {
                    orderField = "A1_CEP";
                } else if (radioOption == 4) {
                    orderField = "A1_MUN, A1_EST";
                }

                if (radioOrientation == 0) {
                    orderOrientation = "ASC";
                } else if (radioOrientation == 1) {
                    orderOrientation = "DESC";
                }

                updateListItens(selectionFilter, selectionFilterArgs);

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ClientListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Client> mClientList;

    Utils utils = Utils.getInstance();

    //Constructor
    public ClientListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Client> mClientList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mClientList = mClientList;
    }

    public void addListItemToAdapter(ArrayList<Client> list) {
        //Add list to current array list of data
        mClientList.addAll(list);
        //Notify UI
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mClientList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mClientList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_client_list, null);

        TextView tv_cod = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_cod);
        TextView tv_cnpj = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_cpnj);
        TextView tv_fantasyName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_fantasyName);
        TextView tv_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        TextView tv_end = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_end);
        TextView tv_creditLimit = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_creditLimit);
        TextView tvSaldoAVencer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_saldo_a_vencer);
        TextView tvSaldoVencido = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_saldo_vencido);

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.showContextMenu();
            }
        });

        Mask mask = Mask.getInstance();

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(",##0.00");

        tv_cod.setText(String.valueOf(mClientList.get(position).getId()));
        tv_cnpj.setText(mask.CGC(mClientList.get(position).getCod()));
        tv_fantasyName.setText(mClientList.get(position).getFantasyName());
        tv_name.setText(mClientList.get(position).getName());
        tv_end.setText(mClientList.get(position).getEnd() + ", " + utils.maskCEP(mClientList.get(position).getCep()) + ", " + mClientList.get(position).getCidade() + " - " + mClientList.get(position).getUf());
        tv_creditLimit.setText("Limite: R$ " + mClientList.get(position).getCreditLimit());
        tvSaldoAVencer.setText("A vencer: R$ " + formatter.format(mClientList.get(position).getSaldoADev()));
        tvSaldoVencido.setText("Vencido: R$ " + formatter.format(mClientList.get(position).getSaldoDev()));

        //Save client id to tag
        v.setTag(mClientList.get(position).getId());

        return v;
    }

    public ArrayList<Client> getmClientList() {
        return mClientList;
    }

    public void setmClientList(ArrayList<Client> mClientList) {
        this.mClientList = mClientList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sao 2 duvidas entao vou separar:

**Bug no fim do scroll**

Eu nao tenho como debugar o codigo pra voce, mas olhando por cima parece que o seu problema deve estar nesse codigo aqui:

```
if(view.getLastVisiblePosition() == totalItemCount-1 && lvClient.getCount() >= limit && isLoading == false) {
```

Esta um pouco confuso entao nao entendi totalmente as regras, mas tem boa possibilidade de alguma dessas condicoes nunca ocorrer e entao nunca dispara  a thread pra carregar mais items. Use o debugger e cheque se ele entra dentro do `if`. Se ele entrar, provavelmente seu erro esta na thread.

**Long click nao funcionando**

Procurei pelo seu codigo, voce nunca setou o `OnLongClickListener` no elemento da sua lista, eu vi que voce da um `setLongClickable`, mas isso sozinho nao eh suficiente, precisa tambem setar o listener como vc ja fez pro clique normal.

[Referencia no SO Gringo pra essa duvida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607479/listview-doesnt-fire-setonlongclicklistener-only-setonitemclicklistener)

Comment: O que acontece é que o click longo nem é o real problema, eu tentei referencia-lo para tentar melhorar o entendimento, mais não deu muito certo. Fiz um teste tirando o limit e a thread deixando listar todos os registros na tela, e no ultimo item funcionou normal o click no imagebuttom.

Comment: @Scussel o seu erro é com certeza nessa parte das condicoes.. Porque ao inves de "escutar" o scroll voce nao controla pelo item que esta sendo exibido na lista (se eh o 1o, 2o, 3o, etc) uma vez que a lista cresce apenas quando chega no final mesmo.. uma ideia que me surgiu hoje

Comment: não entendi muito bem a ideia, consegue exemplificar ?